# Duplicate Oracle Sequence

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5.1, oracle-call-interface

I have a problem about using oracle sequence with yajra/laravel-oci8 library (v.5.1) in Laravel 5.1.

My scenario are:

1. I have a column named `trailer_id` in table A.
2. That column contain ID that generated using sequence named `trailed_id_seq`. Code:

   ```
   function postCreate(Request $request) {
       $id = $request->input('id');

       DB::beginTransaction();

       ....

       $running_no_seq = DB::getSequence();
       $trailer_id = $running_no_seq->nextValue('trailer_id_seq')."";

       for($i=0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
          // Some process, it can take a while here...
       }

       DB::table('A')->where('id',$id)->update([
          'trailer_id' => $trailer_id
       ]);

       DB::commit();
   }
   ```

   The property of `trailer_id_seq` sequence (captured in Navicat apps):
   [image]
3. This function can be called by many users.

The problem is:

Why the `trailer_id` column can be duplicate when accessed by different user in different time?

Here some example: (`created_by` is user ID) 
[image]

**My question**: How is this possible? How can i fixed it? (I can't make `trailer_id` column to unique)

I've read yajra oci docs:
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-oci8/master/sequence , is the code `DB::getSequence()->nextValue('seq_name');` ONLY return next value and not updated the sequence?

Because in oracle docs, `nextval` is increments the sequence and returns the next value (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76989/ch26.htm#4062).

Please help me. Thank you for any answer!